# Variance of a die roll

Tags: variance, standard-deviation

I am a little unclear if this question makes sense. Say I have a fair die with sides 1 to 6. Can I ask what is the variance of a single roll of the die? The calculation I was thinking was the following. $\mu = 3.5$

$$\frac{1}{6}\times\left[2.5^{2} + 1.5^{2} + .5^{2}\right]\times 2 = 2.91$$

So then the standard deviation is 1.70. Does this further mean that within 3.5 $\pm$ 1.7 is 68% of all the outcomes? (Not sure if this makes sense in this example where prob are same for each outcome)

Comment: Why are you posing this as though you have a normal distribution.

Comment: @Michael Although indeed most references do focus on the normal distribution, the 68-95-99.7 rule applies to many non-normal distributions, especially symmetric ones.  The potential misunderstanding here really concerns the way in which a *small discrete* random variable is likely not to conform to this rule.  However, since $3.5\pm 1.7=[1.8, 5.2]$ comprehends four of the six possible results, or $67\%$, the rule works remarkably well.  Furthermore $100\%$ of the results lie within two (or three) sds of the mean and both $95$ and $99.7$ are excellent approximations to $100$ in this context.

Comment: Here the OP is talking about a + or - 1 sigma of 68%. Nothing here about 2 or 3 sigma. The "empirical" works approximately for some symmetric unimodal distributions.  As you say @whuber, this is a discrete distribution that is not necessarily symmetric.

Comment: @Michael The OP is implicitly referring to the *extremely well known* "68-95-99.7" rule taught in many (if not most) stats textbooks.  I doubt they learned a "68" only rule.  BTW, because this is a uniform distribution, it's obviously symmetric.

Comment: So I get it that the 68-95-99.7 rule applies only if you have a sufficiently large sample. But in this case it is just a coincidence that the mean +/-*expected standard deviation* (is this the right term?) happens to fall in the correct interval?

Comment: The answer to the question "can I calculate the variance of a single roll?" is yes (assuming you mean the population variance). You correctly calculated that value for a fair six-sided die. You can also directly calculate the proportion within 1,  2 or 3 sd's of the mean very easily yourself and compare with the "empirical rule" but the empirical rule doesn't apply to everything (whuber says it works quite well in this case, but it's really a matter of how you look at it, what you're using it for and what your tolerance for inaccuracy is; I'd be somewhat less enthusiastic about it myself)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure your question makes sense. Wanting that, here are some ideas about variance:

Variance is a measure of how spread out the sample data are about the mean, or, alternately, how spread out the population values are about the population mean.

If by "a single value" you mean "a single (sample) observation," then the variance must be zero, since the sample mean is just the value of the one observation, and there is no spread of observations about it.

If by "a single value" you mean a single value from the distribution of a fair six-sided die, then, while there is no *spread* of data around (i.e. a distribution of values above and below) the population mean ($\mu=3.5$), there is a *deviation* of the single observation from that population mean: $x-\mu$.

Comment: I would even less inclined to attribute sense to the answer 3.5 ± 1.7 is 68%. Take the mean, perhaps there is a circumstance in which this makes sense, but it cannot be an outcome from a die, which only assume integer values. Without also inserting a context, e.g., two adjudicators and a dirty die, there is no way to get 3.5. Out of context, there is no meaning, at least no primary one.

Comment: @Carl We agree... my answer hoped to kindle little sparks of light for the OP, nothing more. :)

Comment: +1 For making sense in your comment, I would suggest modifying your answer slightly to reflect that as well.

Answer (score -1):

This is a classic example of 'experts' deliberately misinterpreting the intent of the OP's question and refusing to provide a clear answer on the basis that the original question lacked technical precision.  I suspect this is the actual answer you are looking for:

Yes, your calculation is correct.  However, your 68% proposal implicitly assumes a normal distribution.  For a single die roll, this doesn't make much sense.  However, were you to roll a die say 100 times, then a normal distribution would provide a very close approximation to the actual distribution of results.  The more times you roll the die, the better the approximation becomes.

However, now you have to scale the Variance according to the number of die rolls.  The variance of the total scales according to n (100), while the variance of the average scales according to 1/n.  Therefore, if you roll a die 100 times:
Total sum : Expected value 350, Variance roughly 17 (10*1.7)
Average : Expected value 3.5, Variance roughly .17 (1/10*1.7)

And your 68% rule applies.  Notice how the expected value and variance of the total sum is 100 * those of the average.